# Bootstrap radio button data-toggle does not work with ng-model

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I used this [guide](http://codepen.io/BrianSassaman/pen/iLrpC) to design my radio buttons. At first it seems to work, but then I realized that the ng-model does not work anymore (it always takes the initial value). It works when I leave out the data-toggle="buttons" but then I have double checkboxes in my HTML and I am not really sure how to get rid of them.

old HTML (works)

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Audio</label>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="audio" value="real" ng-model="formData.audio" disabled>
                    Real Audio
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="audio" value="chariots" ng-model="formData.audio">
                    Chariots of Fire
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="audio" value="benny" ng-model="formData.audio">
                    Benny Hill
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

new HTML (does not work)

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <label>Audio</label>
          <br>
          <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn active">
              <input type="radio" name="audio" value="chariots" ng-model="formData.audio"><i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-2x"></i><span> Chariots</span>
            </label>
            <label class="btn">
              <input type="radio" name="audio" value="benny" ng-model="formData.audio"><i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-2x"></i><span> Benny Hill</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my js:

```
    $scope.formData = {
        audio: "chariots",
        duration: "2",
        frames: "1.0",
        date: $filter('date')(now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss"),
        filePath: "",
    };
```

[image: First row is without data-toggle="buttons".]

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

You sure there are no errors on console w.r.t dependencies or json formation, because the following seem to work for me :

```
 <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label class="btn active">
        <input type="radio" name="audio" value="chariots" ng-model="formData.audio"><i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-2x"></i><span> Chariots</span>
      </label>
      <label class="btn">
        <input type="radio" name="audio" value="benny" ng-model="formData.audio"><i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-2x"></i><span> Benny Hill</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    Selected : {{formData}}
</div>
```

And :

```
$scope.formData = {
    audio: "chariots"
};
```

Note : Hope you have injected $filter in your controller and the extra comma after filePath is just a typo.

Comment: Yikes ... you were sort of right. Apparantly I added and additional bootstrap.js file (another version) that apparantly messed up the code. Now it works just fine. Thanks a lot.